# Parcelable Data Not Passing Between Activities

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a `List<Movie>` that I want to pass from one activity to another:

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndividualMovieActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Movie", mMovieResultsList.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
```

Movie.Model:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

private int vote_count;
private int id;
private boolean video;
private String title;
private float popularity;
private String poster_path;
private String original_language;
private String original_title;
private ArrayList<String> genre_ids;
private String backdrop_path;
private boolean adult;
private String overview;
private Date release_date;

public Movie(){

}

public Movie(int vote_count, int id, boolean video, String title, float popularity, String poster_path, String original_language, String original_title, ArrayList<String> genre_ids, String backdrop_path, boolean adult, String overview, Date release_date) {
    this.vote_count = vote_count;
    this.id = id;
    this.video = video;
    this.title = title;
    this.popularity = popularity;
    this.poster_path = poster_path;
    this.original_language = original_language;
    this.original_title = original_title;
    this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
    this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    this.adult = adult;
    this.overview = overview;
    this.release_date = release_date;
}

protected Movie(Parcel in) {
    vote_count = in.readInt();
    id = in.readInt();
    video = in.readByte() != 0;
    title = in.readString();
    popularity = in.readFloat();
    poster_path = in.readString();
    original_language = in.readString();
    original_title = in.readString();
    genre_ids = in.createStringArrayList();
    backdrop_path = in.readString();
    adult = in.readByte() != 0;
    overview = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movie(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }
};

public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
    this.vote_count = vote_count;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setVideo(boolean video) {
    this.video = video;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setPopularity(float popularity) {
    this.popularity = popularity;
}

public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
    this.poster_path = poster_path;
}

public void setOriginal_language(String original_language) {
    this.original_language = original_language;
}

public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
    this.original_title = original_title;
}

public void setGenre_ids(ArrayList<String> genre_ids) {
    this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
}

public void setBackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
    this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
}

public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
    this.adult = adult;
}

public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
}

public void setRelease_date(Date release_date) {
    this.release_date = release_date;
}

public int getVote_count() {
    return vote_count;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean isVideo() {
    return video;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public float getPopularity() {
    return popularity;
}

public String getPoster_path() {
    return poster_path;
}

public String getOriginal_language() {
    return original_language;
}

public String getOriginal_title() {
    return original_title;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGenre_ids() {
    return genre_ids;
}

public String getBackdrop_path() {
    return backdrop_path;
}

public boolean isAdult() {
    return adult;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public Date getRelease_date() {
    return release_date;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(vote_count);
    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[]{video});
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeFloat(popularity);
    parcel.writeString(poster_path);
    parcel.writeString(original_language);
    parcel.writeString(original_title);
    parcel.writeStringList(genre_ids);
    parcel.writeString(backdrop_path);
    parcel.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[]{adult});
    parcel.writeString(overview);
    parcel.writeString(String.valueOf(release_date));


  }
```

}

When I try to fetch the data and display in a `TextView`, nothing is displaying indicating that I may not be passing the data correctly:

```
public class IndividualMovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView testText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_individual_movie);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("Movie");
    String title = movie.getOriginal_title();

    testText = findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
    //no text being displayed
    testText.setText(title);

   }
 }
```

**UPDATE**
Full source code can be found here: 
https://github.com/troy21688/PopularMovies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have errors in your Pracelable implementation which makes the data corrupt when read from Parcel.

You should use:

```
parcel.writeByte(theBoolean ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0); // replace `theBoolean` with the real variable name
```

to save boolean values (not `writeBooleanArray`). In your case, `video` and `adult`.

Comment: Where in `writeByte()` do you pass the boolean value? I am trying         `parcel.writeByte((byte) (video ? 1:0));`

Answer (score 1):

To get Parcelable object you need to use

```
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(mKey);
```

And if you have a problem with you Parcelable class try following (getter and setters not added)

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

        private int vote_count;
        private int id;
        private boolean video;
        private String title;
        private float popularity;
        private String poster_path;
        private String original_language;
        private String original_title;
        private ArrayList<String> genre_ids;
        private String backdrop_path;
        private boolean adult;
        private String overview;
        private Date release_date;

        public Movie() {
        }

        protected Movie(Parcel in) {
            this.vote_count = in.readInt();
            this.id = in.readInt();
            this.video = in.readByte() != 0;
            this.title = in.readString();
            this.popularity = in.readFloat();
            this.poster_path = in.readString();
            this.original_language = in.readString();
            this.original_title = in.readString();
            this.genre_ids = in.createStringArrayList();
            this.backdrop_path = in.readString();
            this.adult = in.readByte() != 0;
            this.overview = in.readString();
            long tmpRelease_date = in.readLong();
            this.release_date = tmpRelease_date == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpRelease_date);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new  Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
            @Override
            public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new Movie(source);
            }

            @Override
            public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Movie[size];
            }
        };


        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(this.vote_count);
            dest.writeInt(this.id);
            dest.writeByte(this.video ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
            dest.writeString(this.title);
            dest.writeFloat(this.popularity);
            dest.writeString(this.poster_path);
            dest.writeString(this.original_language);
            dest.writeString(this.original_title);
            dest.writeStringList(this.genre_ids);
            dest.writeString(this.backdrop_path);
            dest.writeByte(this.adult ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
            dest.writeString(this.overview);
            dest.writeLong(this.release_date != null ? this.release_date.getTime() : -1);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getIntent().
Try getExtra().getParcelable("Movie")

Answer (score 1):

You can use this model.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Movie implements Parcelable {

    private int vote_count;
    private int id;
    private boolean video;
    private String title;
    private float popularity;
    private String poster_path;
    private String original_language;
    private String original_title;
    private ArrayList<String> genre_ids;
    private String backdrop_path;
    private boolean adult;
    private String overview;
    private Date release_date;


    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(int vote_count, int id, boolean video, String title, float popularity, String poster_path, String original_language, String original_title, ArrayList<String> genre_ids, String backdrop_path, boolean adult, String overview, Date release_date) {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
        this.id = id;
        this.video = video;
        this.title = title;
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
        this.original_language = original_language;
        this.original_title = original_title;
        this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
        this.adult = adult;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public int getVote_count() {

        return vote_count;
    }

    public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public float getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(float popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public String getOriginal_language() {
        return original_language;
    }

    public void setOriginal_language(String original_language) {
        this.original_language = original_language;
    }

    public String getOriginal_title() {
        return original_title;
    }

    public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getGenre_ids() {
        return genre_ids;
    }

    public void setGenre_ids(ArrayList<String> genre_ids) {
        this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
    }

    public String getBackdrop_path() {
        return backdrop_path;
    }

    public void setBackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public Date getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(Date release_date) {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.vote_count);
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeByte(this.video ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeFloat(this.popularity);
        dest.writeString(this.poster_path);
        dest.writeString(this.original_language);
        dest.writeString(this.original_title);
        dest.writeStringList(this.genre_ids);
        dest.writeString(this.backdrop_path);
        dest.writeByte(this.adult ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeString(this.overview);
        dest.writeLong(this.release_date != null ? this.release_date.getTime() : -1);
    }


    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.vote_count = in.readInt();
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.video = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.popularity = in.readFloat();
        this.poster_path = in.readString();
        this.original_language = in.readString();
        this.original_title = in.readString();
        this.genre_ids = in.createStringArrayList();
        this.backdrop_path = in.readString();
        this.adult = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.overview = in.readString();
        long tmpRelease_date = in.readLong();
        this.release_date = tmpRelease_date == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpRelease_date);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movie(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed a expression in your code

```
protected Movie(Parcel in) {
    vote_count = in.readInt();
    id = in.readInt();
    video = in.readByte() != 0;
    title = in.readString();
    popularity = in.readFloat();
    poster_path = in.readString();
    original_language = in.readString();
    original_title = in.readString();
    genre_ids = in.createStringArrayList();
    backdrop_path = in.readString();
    adult = in.readByte() != 0;
    overview = in.readString();

// here you miss the realease date field. you can use below
    long tmpDate = in.readLong();
    release_date = tmpDate == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpDate);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    ...
    // add corresponding write to parcel
    dest.writeLong(release_date != null ? release_date.getTime() : -1);
}
```